# Error en consulta SQL que está bien

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Tengo la funcion registros para saber los registros que mostrar en la paginacion de una tabla y la SQL esta bien porque la he probado en el phpmyadmin y es así, por eso no entiendo el error.

La primera vez que se llama a esta funcion el parametro que le llega es 1.

```
 public function registros($pagActual)
{
    
        $fila = ($pagActual-1)*$this->paginacion;
    $sql = "select * from viviendas limit :inicio, :longitud";//select * from viviendas limit 0, 5
    $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sql);
    
    $stmt->bindParam(':inicio', $fila);
    $stmt->bindParam(':longitud', $this->paginacion);
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    if($stmt)
    {
        return $stmt;
    }else{
        echo "Algo salió mal en la busqueda de registros";
    }

}
```

Y el error es este
[image]

Comment: estás 100% de que $file y $this->paginacion tienen datos?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error que recibes `the right syntax to use near ''0', '5''` podría ser que a MariaDB no le gustan esos valores como cadenas, encerrados entre comillas simples y solo necesitas especificar el tipo de dato en [->bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
public function registros($pagActual)
{
    
    $fila = ($pagActual-1)*$this->paginacion;
    $sql = "select * from viviendas limit :inicio, :longitud";//select * from viviendas limit 0, 5
    $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($sql);
    
    // Especificar tipo de dato: Número entero
    $stmt->bindParam(':inicio', $fila, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':longitud', $this->paginacion, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    if($stmt)
    {
        return $stmt;
    }else{
        echo "Algo salió mal en la busqueda de registros";
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias Triby si era eso de especificar el tipo de dato, nunca lo había usado. Gracias